# Как разместить динамические элементы чтобы страница не прокручивалась

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть 3 обьекта. Заголовок, текст, кнопка. Заголовок может расширяться до зеленой зоны. Текст может расширяться до кнопки дальше нужная прокутка только для текста. Как все это сделать чтобы страница не прокучивалась?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: position: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Задайте высоту блока с текстом и добавьте стиль overflow: scroll;
Будет прокручиваться только текст